# Ajax checkbox checked wont work

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, html, icheck

I have a checkbox with id `#cond99`; it's loaded form ajax, and that's working okay but I want to add an action and it's not working. Can anyone help me?

```
jQuery = window.parent.jQuery;   
jQuery(document).ready(function ()   
{    
   jQuery('input.styled').iCheck(   
   {    
       checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-orange',   
       radioClass: 'iradio_minimal-orange',  
       increaseArea: '40%' // optional  
   });      
   jQuery('input.styled').iCheck('update');   
   jQuery("#cond999").bind("change", function ()  
   {   
       jQuery('#conditions_more').toggle();   
   });   
});
```

Comment: @JamesMontagne - http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/

Comment: iCheck is plugin to stylize checkboxes and radios

https://github.com/damirfoy/iCheck

Comment: It's possible that `iCheck` doesn't fire the underlying checkbox's change event.

Comment: but that plugin is quite good and support `.on('ifChecked', function (event) ` and its working fine thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's loaded dynamically you can use event delegation -

```
jQuery(document).on("change","#cond999", function () {
      jQuery('#conditions_more').toggle();
});
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '#cond999', function () {
    jQuery('#conditions_more').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting your #cond999 element as an Ajax, it might not be available when document.ready event fires, and therefore, you cant bind anything to it.

You might consider binding this event at a callback of an Ajax request that inserts the checkbox into the code.

Comment: i used .on('ifChecked', function (event) from iCheck lib